# Calculation of an Integral Using the Cauchy Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, line-integrals, cauchy-integral-formula

I need assistance with calculating the following integral using the Cauchy formula. I have been encountering incorrect results and would greatly appreciate your help in identifying the mistake in my calculations.

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos t}{5-3\cos t}dt$$

My calculation:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos t}{5-3\cos t}dt = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\frac{e^{it} + e^{-it}}{2}}{5 - 3\frac{e^{it} + e^{-it}}{2}}dt = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{(e^{it})^2 + 1}{-3(e^{it})^{2} + 10e^{it} -3}dt = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{(e^{it})^2 + 1}{-3(e^{it})^{2} + 10e^{it} -3}\frac{d(e^{it})}{ie^{it}} = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{z^{2} + 1}{-3z^{2} + 10z - 3}\frac{d(z)}{iz} = -i\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{z^{2} + 1}{z(-3z^{2} + 10z - 3)}dz$$

Where $\gamma (t)=e^{it}$ is Line (In terms of line integral)

I have calculated the roots and got:
$$-i\oint_{\gamma}^{}\frac{z^{2} + 1}{z(z-3)(z-\frac{1}{3})}dz = -i\oint_{\gamma}^{}\frac{\frac{z^{2} + 1}{z - 3}}{z(z-\frac{1}{3})}$$

After this I have calculated partial fraction decomposition and used Cauchy formula:

$$-i\oint{}^{}3\frac{\frac{z^{2} + 1}{z - 3}}{z} - 3\frac{\frac{z^{2} + 1}{z - 3}}{z - \frac{1}{3}} = -3i\cdot2\pi i\cdot \frac{0 + 1}{0 - 3} + 3i\cdot2\pi i \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{9} + 1}{\frac{1}{3} - 3} =\frac{\pi}{2}$$

But the correct result is: $\frac{\pi}{6}$

Comment: Your partial fractions are not correct. Recombining them shows there's an errant factor of $3$:$$3\frac{\frac{z^{2} + 1}{z - 3}}{z} - 3\frac{\frac{z^{2} + 1}{z - 3}}{z - \frac{1}{3}} = -\color{red}{3}\frac{z^2+1}{z(3z^2-10z+3)}$$This of course contributes directly to your incorrect result.

Comment: @user170231 I have calculated the partial fractions for $\frac{1}{z(z-\frac{1}{3})}$
and I got: $\frac{3}{z} + \frac{-3}{z - \frac{1}{3}}$, Maybe I plugged them in wrong way in the equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying mistake is in the factorization of the denominator and subsequent partial fraction expansion:

$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align*}
& \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos t}{5-3\cos t} \, dt \\
&= \oint\limits_{\gamma:\lvert z\rvert=1} \frac{z+\frac1z}{10-3\left(z+\frac1z\right)} \, \frac{dz}{iz} \\
&= -\frac i{\color{red}{3}} \oint_\gamma \frac{z^2+1}{z \left(z-\frac13\right) (z-3)} \, dz \\
&= -\frac i{\cancel3} \oint_\gamma \left(\frac{\cancel3}{z-\frac13} - \frac{\cancel3}z\right)\underbrace{\frac{z^2+1}{z-3}}_{=:f(z)} \, dz \\ \\
&= -i \cdot 2\pi i \left(f\left(\frac13\right) - f(0)\right) = \boxed{\frac\pi6}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, but I can't find where the 3 in $-\frac{i}{3}$ came from?

Comment: $3z^2-10z+3=(z-3)(\color{red}{3}z-1)=\color{red}3(z-3)\left(z-\dfrac13\right)$